# Date HTML field doesn't get saved to the DB anymore after changing the HTML5 Calendar to a JQuery clendar

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets, calendar

I have this field for inputting a date. It gets saved in to the database through a Servlet.

Earlier I have used the HTML5 Calendar for this input field. But doesn't support Firefox. So I changed that to [this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) jQuery calendar. But it doesn't get saved to the DB any more after doing so. There is no visible error in the logs.

The input field

```
  <!-- Text input-->

              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">License Issued Date</label>
              <div class="col-md-3">

                <input id="datepicker" name="textLicIssuedDt" type="text" class="form-control input-md" value="<c:out value="${drvLicenseLst.dateDrivingLicenseIssued}"/>">
```

Calendar's jquery

```
<!--cal--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>            
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
 <!--cal-->
```

this is the servlet code that saves it to the DB (Hibernate).

```
     int idEmployee=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idEmployee"));
    String licenseNo=request.getParameter("textLicenseNo");
    Date   licIssuedDt=Common.convertJavaDateToSQL(request.getParameter("textLicIssuedDt")); //date picker's field

    boolean remainderStatus=false;   

    Employee employee=new Employee();            
    DrivinglicenseService licenseService=new DrivinglicenseService();

    employee.setIdEmployee(idEmployee);

    Drivinglicense driLicense=licenseService.findByForkey(idEmployee);           

    driLicense.setEmployee(employee);
    driLicense.setDrivingLicenseNumber(licenseNo);
    driLicense.setDateDrivingLicenseIssued(licIssuedDt); 
    driLicense.setDateCreated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());

    driLicense.setLastUpdated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());

    licenseService.saveOrUpdate(driLicense);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to debug this, to see where the data gets lost ?
(empty input, datepicker not called, empty in form, format different than expected...)